# How to update app content when app is suspended in background

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an Android app that has a service that handle Firebase messages. So far it's working for me and I receive messages properly even when app is in background. What I need is somehow update app content when a message is received. That mean use network to contact backend and download fairly long JSON data and put them in database.

I have model in repository which I use in Activity. Now I am considering whenever I have to somehow call activity and refresh data but I think activity is somewhat dead when app is in background? So I don't know if it is even possible.

I can download data inside the service but my understanding of service is that it shall be lightweight and all the model and network calls seems to be a bit overkill for the service. Am I wrong?

What is ideal solution considering standard android architectural approach? Thank you.

Comment: You can use WorkManager to schedule a `OneTimeWorkRequest` as soon as you receive a Firebase message & fetch your data from the backend & locally store it. On the next app launch, compare the store data & decide if any action is required.

Comment: Thank you I haven't consider WorkManagers. Unfortunately I need to update the data immediately. I was considering to call for action too. That mean a notification that will notify user about new data and ask to open the app to get them.

Comment: And yet another thing to consider. The database would be open from multiple processes which could lead to problems I guess? Honestly I never worked with one DB from multiple processes.

Comment: `OneTimeWorkRequest` is fired immediately if not used with `setInitialDelay`. For multi-process handling, WorkManager supports multiprocess as well via `RemoteWorkManager`.